# Dynamically set the legend color for a line chart in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a line chart which shows the number of units sold per day for the past 4 months. The X-axis are days, Y-axis is the number of units, and the legend is the month (Month part of date filtered for Top 4).[image: Sample Graph]

I want to keep the color scheme of the legend the same as the new data is added and months move forward, so the most recent month is always the same color. For example in the sample graph, when Nov data is added, Nov will be Yellow, Oct will be Dark blue, Sep will be light blue, and Aug will be red.

The line chart has no conditional formatting as far as my searches could find. I added a new column with the rank of the month which in turn I can use as legends and keep the colors, but that way, the legend on the chart will remain the same as well (I can turn it into values like "current month", "past month", ...). But I was wondering is there a way to keep the real names on the legend and have the colors dynamically updated?